# How to setup sendgrid with magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, smtp

I was trying to setup sendgrid SMTP with magento 2 with latest  Sendgrid settings.
But didn't found anything helpful.
Anyone can help what settings should I use in magento admin for sendgrid SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create smtp keys :
[image]

[image]

After this you will get an api key. Make sure you save this key secret on a safe place.
Now you will need to go to magento admin.Fill the following details , everything will remain same only in password you will need to enter the key you created.
[image]

Comment: getting Unauthenticated senders not allowed error

Comment: On sendgrid end or Magento?

Comment: magento end.. when sending test email.